# How to use Hamcrest to test for exception?

Tags: groovy, hamcrest

I have the following code:

```
def f(String s) {
  assert !s?.contains('.')
}
```

What Hamcrest matcher can be used to test the assertion? I know I can use a `try`/`catch` block but I prefer keeping the cyclomatic complexity of tests to one.

Comment: Check the matcher I wrote, see EDIT in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you REALLY must use Hamcrest, you could write something like:

```
assertThat( { f( 'hi.ho' ) }, thrown( MyException ) )
```

You will need the `ThrownMatcher.thrown(..)` matcher which I wrote just for fun.

See [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/renatoathaydes/6907103).

But in Groovy, Hamcrest matchers can be easily replaced with more powerful constructs.

You could, for example, use [GroovyTestCase](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyTestCase.html) to do this:

```
shouldFail( MyException, { /* code expected to throw MyException*/ } )
```

Finally, if you're serious about testing use Spock:

http://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics

Example

```
when:
f 'something.something'

then:
thrown( TypeOfException )
```

Comment: I know about Spock but due to constraints cannot use it for testing.

Comment: I like the Hamcrest answer, but would feel better up-voting it and checking it if it were a separate answer.

Comment: I agree, but I don't think it's ok to remove an answer or answer twice... so I just edited to have the ACTUAL answer first, and my suggestion about Spock last so the answer contents is still the same.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to answer twice. Did you try?