# Concise 'assert that closure throws' expression for Groovy Unit Tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, closures, assertions

I need something like:

```
assertThat({throw new Exception("hey!")}).throws(Exception).hasMessage("hey!");
```

In Java I used a standard approach, but it's too much for a language with closures:

```
try{
    throw new Exception("hey!");
    fail("not thrown");
}catch (Exception e){
    assertThat(e).hasMessage("hey!");
}
```

Using frameworks like JUnit, Hamcrest, Fest or Mockito is very welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Hamcrest to test for exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256175/how-to-use-hamcrest-to-test-for-exception) (not sure if this completely covers your use-case)

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I have found a close alternative with `GroovyAssert.shouldFail`, but can't check a message returned.

Comment: It appears that the return value of `shouldFail` is the message, which allows you to assert on it: http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/groovy-goodness-testing-for-expected.html (I haven't tried this, no idea if it actually works ;))

Comment: Thank you, it actually does, I've put an example below on what I have found.

Answer (score 2):

The closest match I have found with a help of @OliCharlesworth is `assertThat` from the [FestAssert](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x) library and `shouldFail` from [GroovyAssert](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/test/GroovyAssert.html):

```
assertThat(shouldFail(Exception, {throw new Exception("hey")})).hasMessage("hey")
```